Combine Okta and Entra Authentication schemes in ASP.NET Core MVC app
I want to combine Okta and Entra authentication schemes in ASP.NET Core MVC app.
Program.cs:
// Okta
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn");
    })
    .AddOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions
    {
        OktaDomain = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:OktaDomain"),
        ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientId"),
        ClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientSecret"),
        AuthorizationServerId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:AuthorizationServerId"),
        Scope = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "email" },
    });

// Entra
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

However, I get this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Cookies'

How can I combine the two, so internal users will authenticate with Entra, whereas external users will authenticate with Okta?

Please share your configuration file.

I guess AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp adds its own cookie handler, so in your setup you now haw two cookie handlers. You could remove your AddCookie, and just use the one provided by AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp. But in general, I think you will have a lot of issues with that setup, as for example, the access tokens received with have different content. how will the API's receving the access tokens be able to trust them?

When using AddAuthentication, it can only be used once. Here is the modified sample code.

@StanSm789 You can fix the issue by adding the below code in the Program.cs class for the cookies.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OktaScheme";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
})


System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Cookies

I fixed the above error by adding cookie authentication for okta and Entra authentication in the Program.cs class.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OktaScheme";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
})

Program.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OktaScheme";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("OktaScheme", options =>
{
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
    options.Authority = $"{builder.Configuration["Okta:OktaDomain"]}/oauth2/{builder.Configuration["Okta:AuthorizationServerId"]}";
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/authorization-code/callback");
})
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(options);
    options.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
}, null, "EntraScheme", null);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();

AccountController.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication11.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SignIn(string userType)
        {
            if (userType == "internal")
            {
                return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, "EntraScheme");
            }
            else
            {
                return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, "OktaScheme");
            }
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SignOut()
        {
            return SignOut(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "OktaScheme", "EntraScheme");
        }
    }
}

appsettings.json :
{
  "Okta": {
    "OktaDomain": "https://<domain>.okta.com",
    "ClientId": "<clientID>",
    "ClientSecret": "<clientSecret>",
    "AuthorizationServerId": "default"
  },
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<domain>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "<tenantID>",
    "ClientId": "<clientID>",
    "CallbackPath": "/authorization-code/callback"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

